# Cannot repair bcd because the windows installation cannot be found

Tags: windows, uefi, gpt, efi, bcd

I'm trying to rebuild my BCD but my windows7 installation cannot be found.

So far, I have typed these commands from the Windows7 install DVD (which I booted in UEFI mode) :

```all-dos
X:\sources>chkdsk /r c:
X:\sources>bcdedit /export C:\BCDBackup
The operation completed successfully.
X:\sources>attrib c:\boot\bcd -h -r -s
X:\sources>ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
X:\sources>bootrec /rebuildbcd
Scanning all disks for Windows installations.

Please wait, since this may take a while...

Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 0
The operation completed successfully.
X:\sources>attrib c:\bootmgr -h -r -s
X:\sources>ren c:\bootmgrbackup
X:\sources>bootrec /rebuildbcd
Scanning all disks for Windows installations.

Please wait, since this may take a while...

Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 0
The operation completed successfully.
```

Still, Windows cannot be found.

Here is some useful information about my PC (which I booted from a French install DVD of Windows) therefore, you will notice I translated into English the best I could :

`diskpart` info. on my GPT disk :

```
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB   456 GB        *

  Partition ###   Type              Size     Offset
  -------------   ----------------  -------  --------
  Partition 1     Primary             19 G    1024 K
  Partition 2     Primary            255 G      19 G
  Partition 3     System             550 M     275 G
  Partition 4     Primary            199 G     275 G

  Volume ###   Ltr  Nom          Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------   ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0      E   GSP1RMCHPXF  UDF    DVD-ROM     3102 M   Healthy
  Volume 1          PQSERVICE    NTFS   Partition     19 G   Healthy
  Volume 2      C   Windows7     NTFS   Partition    255 G   Healthy
  Volume 3      D   Donnees      NTFS   Partition    199 G   Healthy
  Volume 4          EFI_SYSTEMP  FAT32  Partition    550 M   Healthy    System
  Volume 5      F                       Removable        0 o  0 media
  Volume 6      G   MULTISYSTEM  FAT32  Removable      43 G   Healthy
```

`bcdedit` info. :

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}  
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {e0e194f6-21df-11e9-9f00-de2495574b25}
displayorder            {default}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {e0e194f6-21df-11e9-9f00-de2495574b25}
nx                      OptIn
detecthal               Yes
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: When the BCD file system on your system is corrupted, you will not be able to access the operating system. I used EaseUS Partition Master and It solved my problem https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/the-requested-system-device-cannot-be-found.html